# jquery ColorBox - Inline content only displayed the first time

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I can't seem to get my very basic ColorBox sample working.

It is a simple inline div that displays correctly the first time but after that there is just simply no content to display (colorbox appears very small - inspecting shows no content inside).

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Colorbox Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- Add colorbox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/colorbox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('a.enter').colorbox({inline:true});
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
       <div class="wrapper">
        <a class="enter" href="#entrydiv">Click To Enter</a> 
       </div>
        <div style="display:none">
            <div id="entrydiv">
                <h2>Enter your details below</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone give me any pointers. I've looked through most of the related questions on SO and none of them seem to be exactly the same.

Have tested on both Safari and Firefox on the Mac

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a demo ? It's working on demos. http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example2/

Comment: Must have a problem with my version of colorbox.js. When I created the demo in JSBin and linked to the latest version on github the problem stopped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Grabbed the latest version of Colorbox from GitHub and it solved the issue